# Google chart failing to load from local JSON source

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, google-visualization

## The problem

I have a site where multiple charts are running in one go. Say anywhere from 5-7. At the moment there is page block while all the data is loaded before it then loads the charts.

What I wanted to try and achieve here was to fire my render function on a per chart basis, the moment the data is done. So what I am trying to do is model the below for each chart I have.

#### What I've tried

***JS:***

```
// chart basics
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['timeline']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//container
var container = document.getElementById('chart_div_23_36');
  
//begin our function
function drawChart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/data.json',
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(jsonData) {
  
    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData); 
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    chart.draw(data, {
          width: 924, 
          height: 340,
          enableInteractivity : false,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          avoidOverlappingGridLines: false
      });

  }).fail(function() {
    google.visualization.errors.addError(container, 
      "Failed to load data for the chart.");
  });
}
//end function
```

***HTML:***

Excuse the strange div names, they are pregenerated from a back-end system.

```
<div id="chart_div_23_36"></div>
```

And the contents of my ***JSON*** file:

```
{
"cols": [
{"id":"Day","label":"Day","pattern":"","type":"string"},
{"id":"Name","label":"Name","pattern":"","type":"string"},
{"id":"Color","label":"Color","pattern":"","type":"string","role":"style"},
{"id":"Start","label":"Start","pattern":"","type":"date"},
{"id":"End","label":"End","pattern":"","type":"date"}
],
"rows": [
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,10,0,0)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,10,13,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#FF0000","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,10,13,58)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,10,17,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,10,17,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,10,30,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,11,0,0)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,11,13,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#FF0000","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,11,13,58)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,11,17,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,11,17,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,11,30,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,0,0)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,5,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#33CC33","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,5,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,6,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,6,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,7,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#0066ff","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,7,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,8,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,8,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,12,30,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,13,0,0)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,13,13,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#FF0000","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,13,13,58)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,13,17,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,13,17,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,13,30,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,14,0,0)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,14,13,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#FF0000","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,14,13,58)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,14,17,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,14,17,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,14,30,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,0,0)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,1,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#33CC33","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,1,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,2,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,2,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,3,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#0066ff","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,3,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,4,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,4,59)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,15,30,59)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#CCCCCC","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,16,0,0)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,16,13,58)","f":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Tue 15/03/16","f":null},{"v":"","f":null},{"v":"#FF0000","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,16,13,58)","f":null},{"v": "Date(2013,10,10,16,17,59)","f":null}]},
]
}
```

#### Errors

> Failed to load data for the chart.

I am getting the error from my `.fail` part of the AJAX call. The only problem is I can't understand why. It all looks right to me and I've tried many variants of this.

I am seeing the fetching of the JSON file itself:
[image]

Comment: Did you check in inspector is the URL called right (Code 200)?

Comment: I would recommend checking the actual error causing the `fail` -- add the necessary arguments --> `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/) the provided JSON data is not valid, it prevents JSON file to be loaded.

Once the [JSON data is fixed](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/a32a35e5e22170e2c9f0), the data file is loaded and chart is rendered properly as demonstrated below:

```js
// chart basics
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['timeline']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



//begin our function
function drawChart() {

  //container
  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div_23_36');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vgrem/a32a35e5e22170e2c9f0/raw/950256440645ae5b506fb18547cbaa0261a1d5bc/data.json',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false
  }).done(function(jsonData) {

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData); 

    
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    chart.draw(data, {
          width: 924, 
          height: 340,
          enableInteractivity : false,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          avoidOverlappingGridLines: false
      });

  }).fail(function(error) {
    google.visualization.errors.addError(container, 
      "Failed to load data for the chart.");
  });
}
//end function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div_23_36"></div>
```